# Is "reset" an Excel/VBA reserved keyword?

Tags: excel, vba, keyword, reset

I looked up into several web sites, including MSDN, and "Reset" doesn't seem to be a reserved keyword or a function. However, if I just write "Reset" on a stand-alone line in my VBA code, it executes correctly. My assumption is that it does indeed run some sort of predefined "reset" function, but couldn't find any reference to it anywhere. Now it is mainly a curiosity, but I spent a few hours trying to understand why a sub written by me with the name "Reset" was behaving differently from the same sub named, for instance, "Reset2". If anybody wants to know more about this aspect I can post some code, but it probably won't be necessary if it just turns out that "Reset" is a pre-defined routine. Thanks

Comment: Yes, its a built-in statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278556(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find with a few google searches!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built-in Visual Basic for Applications editor in Excel `reset` as a name doesn't bring any trouble.

`Reset` is no reserved keyword in VBA.
[`Reset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be4e61a2(v=vs.90).aspx) is a function name in VB only.